# JSF, panelGrid spaces between items

Tags: jsf, panelgrid

I have this code, I want to gain advantage of the left space (Not filed value)...

```
            [![<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" >
                <p:outputLabel value="Field1:" for="itField1" />
                <p:inputText id="itField1" style="width:200px" required="true"
                             value="#{bean.field1}">
                </p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="Field2:" for="itField2" />
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:200px"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                    <p:inputText id="itField2" required="true" 
                         value="#{="#{bean.field2}"
                         />
                    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-search"
                                     />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:outputLabel value="Field3:" for="itField3" />
                <p:inputText id="itField3" style="width:200px" required="true"
                             value="#{bean.field3}">
                </p:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>]
```

**I want this!**
[image]

But, I get that :( [image] :

How to do it?

Comment: The answer to your Question is CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding **CSS** style `width:100%` to `<p:inputText id="itField2" ..... />` and `<p:commandButton .... />`as follows:

```
<p:inputText id="itField2" value="#{bean.field2}" required="true" style="width:100%"  />
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-search" style="width:100%" />
```